# es6 code snipping which is not clear

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I need to use this code and we have problem with ES lint which is give red as rule for the keyword const (I know how to overcome this) but Im not sure that I really understand this code,my question is how it should be written in ES5 (instead of the const since it's getting two param...)

```
const {code, warnings} = bab.transform('var f = function(){};', ['let', 'arrow']);
```

I try with var etc without success

i've tried also with babel to do the opposite  without success

http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=react%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBA3qAJgUwDQwO4EMBOYCWYA5hAL4wC8MANsgEZZ0B0UOWkAZiDgLYAUAcgBuuGB0piArmGBR84PgEo4pANwD0AbQG0oGmANw4QGAQF1FqoA&playground=true

Comment: Your attempt with Babel didn't work because you had an undeclared identifier. But if you'd asked it to just handle `const {code, warnings} = {};`, it would have shown you `var _ref = {}, code = _ref.code, warnings = _ref.warnings;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a *destructuring assignment*. In ES5 it would look like this:

```
var result = bab.transform('var f = function(){};', ['let', 'arrow']);
var code = result.code;
var warnings = result.warnings;
```

(Obviously, though, the ES2015 code doesn't have the `result` variable.) Or if you want something that doesn't leave the `result` variable around:

```
var code, warnings;
(function() {
    var result = bab.transform('var f = function(){};', ['let', 'arrow']);
    code = result.code;
    warnings = result.warnings;
})();
```